# Использование библиотек GWT

Tags: ant, gwt, java, build

Такая ситуация. У меня два GWT проекта, лежащие в разных под папках одной папки. Один проект - это библиотека контролов, другой - должен использовать эти контролы. Как сделать так, чтобы второй проект мог использовать код контролов из первого?

Answer (score 1):

В файле web2.gwt.xml второго проекта (там где будет использоваться),
добавляем

```
<inherits name="com.web"/>
```

Где com.web - первый проект (com/web.gwt.xml).
В коде второго проекта используете, как вам нужно.

Если нужна серверная часть, не забыть поправить web.xml.

В web.xml второго проекта должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
    <!--Это было-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Web2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.web2.server.Web2ServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Web2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web2/Web2Service</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- 
      Это добавили из первого (изменив мапинг с /web/webService на /web2/webService)
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.web.server.webServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web2/webService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Стоит пояснить, что подключенный проект, в нашем случае первый, также срабатывает (т.е. попадает в метод onModuleLoad точки входа первого проекта)

Если что-то не понятно, пишите - поясню.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от того, каким образом построены ваши проекты, каким средствами они собираются. Если это ant и вы уверены, что взаимное расположение проектов не будет меняться, то можете антом пнуть сначала проект с контролами, а потом результат использовать во время сборки основного проекта. Что же касается IDE, то это уже depends on. Всегда есть способ настроить classpath.